# jamesDBloom mockserver verify with javascript

Tags: javascript, mocking

I'm trying to verify some request that i have sent via mockServer  http://www.mock-server.com/

the server shows that i have sent the request, but when trying the verifying it says request not found at least once.

the request looks like this:
    for request:

```
{
  "method" : "GET",
  "path" : "myPath",
......
```

then my set up veryfication verifycation shows like this in the logs

```
{
  "httpRequest" : {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path" : "myPath"
  },
  "times" : {
    "count" : 1,
    "exact" : false
  }
}
```

in my opinion these two should match, but i receive a text saying request not found at least once.

any helpful idea how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking in the logs you should see an output as follows:

```
2015-07-02 07:27:22,045 INFO o.m.m.HttpRequestMatcher request:

    {
      "method" : "GET",
      "path" : "/myPath",
      ...
    }

 did not match expectation:

    {
      "path" : "/myPath"
    }

 because:

    method matches = true
    path matches = false
    query string parameters match = true
    body matches = true
    headers match = true
    cookies match = true
    cookies match = true
    cookies match = true
    keep-alive matches = true
    ssl matches = true
```

That log message will tell you exactly what did not match when you tried to perform the verification.

If this does not help then you can try using TRACE level logging that will output why each matcher does not match.  However this can produce a lot of logs that you need to check.  The important thing to remember is when you call verify it will test you verification against every single request received so far, this means if you are debugging try to isolate only the single request that failing the verification to reduce the amount of logs.